# swipe and click to next slide

Tags: user-experience, flickity

With flickity, is it possible to have two behaviours at the same time on the same slide?

- swipe (default and better four touch screen)
- click to next slide (better for desktop)

I tried something like:

```
var carouselCells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-cell'))
  carouselCells.forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    flckty.next();
  })
})
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/francoisromain/fum7Lrac/

The click works fine but the problem is the swipe moves forwards two slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Flickity's staticClick event over standard click, as click is triggered during drag.

```
flkty.on( 'staticClick', function() {
  flkty.next()
})
```

from: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/486#issuecomment-258686221